# Return multiple rows from a recursive stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, return-value

I would like to return multiple rows as a result from a stored procedure. I am calling this stored procedure recursively, to read all nested values.

This is my current procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST 
(
  MATERIAL_H IN VARCHAR2,
) AS
BEGIN
  FOR R IN (SELECT COMPONENT FROM TTP10.PSMS WHERE MATERIAL = MATERIAL_H) LOOP
    TEST (R.COMPONENT);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(R.COMPONENT); -- Each COMPONENT should be one row in the result
  END LOOP;
END TEST;
```

**Edit**

If added an example of the database records. As you can see the `MATERIAL 1` is composed of multiple `COMPONENT (89, 90, 91)`. Those components can also be composed of other components, like `COMPONENT (90, 5)`.

My stored procedure read all relationships between the materials and components. I would like to get all nested components in a material.

`MATERIAL 1: (89, 90, 91, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4)`

```
+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
| MATERIAL  | COMPONENT |  | MATERIALS  | COMPONENT |
+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
|     1     |     89    |  |      2     |    NULL   |
+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
|     1     |     90    |  |      3     |    NULL   |
+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
|     1     |     91    |  |      4     |    NULL   |
+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
|     90    |     5     |  |      6     |    NULL   |
+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
|     90    |     6     |  |      7     |    NULL   |
+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
|     90    |     7     |  |     91     |    NULL   |
+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
|     5     |     2     |  |     89     |    NULL   |
+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
|     5     |     3     |  |            |           |
+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
|     5     |     4     |  |            |           |
+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
```

My stored procedure workes fine, it prints all nested relationships between the materials and components.

How could I return the output from `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(R.COMPONENT);` as result? Please notice, I am not able to change the database structure.

Comment: As per my understanding you can use recursive `FUNCTION` to return a value. You can make question bit clear

Comment: You would like to return multiple rows or multiple columns?

Comment: @Exhausted Please have a look at my **Edit**. I hope that helps to understand the problem.

Comment: @Polppan Multiple rows.

Comment: @hofmeister Try this http://stackoverflow.com/q/13225532/599528

Comment: @hofmeister Hope this will be useful https://community.oracle.com/thread/173559

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply go with SQL statement to find such relationship, here no need of recursive statement

```
SQL> desc material
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -------

 MAT                                                NUMBER
 COMPONENT                                          NUMBER
```

I have inserted your sample values the sql statement is like

```
select 
    distinct a.component
from 
 material a
where a.component is not null
START WITH a.mat = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR a.component= a.mat;
```

The output is like below

```
SQL> select
  2     distinct a.component
  3  from
  4   material a
  5  where a.component is not null
  6  START WITH a.mat = 1
  7  CONNECT BY PRIOR a.component= a.mat
  8  ;

 COMPONENT
----------
        89
         6
         7
         5
         2
         3
        91
        90
         4

9 rows selected.
```

If you want for other value, you can try by changing value `1` to other value. The above can be embedded in your procedure to return.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had a similar approch, but this one is much nicer. How could I "return" the result in a stored procedure? With help of a `cursor`?

Comment: use `OBJECT TYPE` varaible to return and cursor can be used rarely

Comment: Do you have a small example, how to return a list of `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764229/how-to-return-multiple-rows-from-oracle-stored-procedure-from-multiple-cursors